# The shift strategy for Francis’s algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

In the Francis’s algorithm, we usually pick the shift to be the eigenvalue of bottom right corner 2 by 2 block matrix from the n by n large matrix namely:
$$eig(\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n} \\
a_{n,n-1} & a_{n,n} 
\end{bmatrix})$$

Also, a shift strategy is beefily described as $|p(λ_{n−m+1})/p(λ_{n−m})| \leq 1.$ and if so, the a_{n−m+1,n-m} entry will converge to zero rapidly, this piece of information is in the PDF from Sebastian Gant. I post the link at here [Chasing the Bulge
by Sebastian Gant](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_17/papers17/sebastian.pdf)

However, I don't understand why this works, basically, my question has two parts

First, why choosing the bottom right corner would make algorithm converge faster?

Second, why $|p(λ_{n−m+1})/p(λ_{n−m})| \leq 1.$ would make the a_{n−m+1,n-m} entry will converge to zero rapidly?

I just need some intuitive explanation for this question.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you understand and what not? A simple answer is that the progression towards good approximations of the eigenvalues is fastest in the lower right corner of the matrix, and thus the shift parameters you get from there the most suited to work towards a matrix split. Is that on the level you understand or that you have questions about?

Comment: @LutzLehmann So, basic I have question about this, I want to find some explanation for why choosing the lower right corner of the matrix will make the progression towards good approximations faster. Even not a formal proof, some intuitive explanation would be good enough for me